# Why await not right working with reject error

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

Why promise catch not working with await?

I want catch error when rejected, but I got two differences result

```
(async () => {
    var t = (new Promise((r1, r2) => r2(12345))); 
    t.catch(e=> console.log(e)); 
    await t; 
})()
```

Results in error: `VM5989:1 Uncaught (in promise)`

```
(async () => {
    var t = (new Promise((r1, r2) => r2(12345))).catch(e=> console.log(e));
    await t; 
})()
```

Causes no error and returns 12345

demo image:

[image]

at `node@12` / `chrome@75 console` , I got the two differences result.

when I use `t.catch`, I got `Unhandled promise rejection`.

when I use `(new Promise()).catch`, I got except result.

why? And how I can use `t` and get the right result?

Comment: In the first example `t` contains a rejected promise and you `await` for it. `await`ing a rejected promise throws an exception. In the second example `t` contains a resolved promise. `await`ing a resolved promise returns a resolved value.

Comment: Because the `.catch` isn't actually part of the promise chain `t`. You've created a second chain with error handling that then goes ignored. If you did `t = t.catch(...)` you'd see different behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you create a new promise that handles the exception by calling `t.catch()`, but you don't assign it to `t`, so `t` remains a promise with an unhandled rejection.

In the second example, `t` references the chain which is a promise with a handled rejection (the `.catch()` continuation does not throw so it resolves with `undefined`), so awaiting `t` will not cause the `async` function to throw.

However, because `t` in the first example still contains a rejected promise, awaiting it will cause the `async` function to throw.

Answer (score -2):

In the first case, since `Promise` is asynchronous in nature and statement r2 was already executed even before attaching the catch.

That means catch was not present when r2 - reject function - was called.

<s>Whenever you reject while using promise then catch must be present. Otherwise, it's obvious to see an error on reject.</s>

Edit: 
As answered by @Patrick Roberts,

the error is not due to unhandled catch but because of the awating for `rejected` `t`. While in the case of the second statement `t` (promise) was still `pending`.

Comment: `var p = new Promise((r1, r2) => r2(12345)); p.catch(() => {});` Look, no uncaught rejections even though the catch was added in the next statement.

Comment: Sorry, I understood it now, the promise was rejected awaiting for the rejected promise which was unhandled thus throws an error. Updating my answer giving reference to your (@PatrickRoberts) answer.